# How can I find a link by URL in my functional test?

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, domcrawler, symfony3.x

In the [Symfony testing documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#links), it shows how to select a link containing specific text:

```
$crawler->selectLink('Click here');
```

But the link I'm looking for won't always have the same text. It will say one of a few different things depending on the status of the record, so instead, I need to find it by URL. I think I can figure out how to do it using an xpath filter. Is that what I should go for, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be testing against a known state - and so that state will inform what text should be on the button.

If not - you can also search by a CSS ID, or enough other information to uniquely identify the button, such as a class name of a button within a range specified by an ID, with a CSS Path, or XPath.

```
Full CSS Path to the `<code>` block in your question
#question > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.postcell > div > div.post-text > pre > code

Xpath
//*[@id="question"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/pre/code
```

A specific ID, or the text to look for would be a lot easier though, and far less likely to break!

Comment: "Testing against a known state." Of course. I was really on the wrong track. I was thinking of finding the link by URL and then verifying that its text was one of the proper values. But really I think I need to test each state and verify that the correct link text for that state is present instead.